# WIF 4.5 Local Development STS not running?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wif

I've recently repaved my machine with Windows 8 Pro x64 and Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.  This has generally made me quite happy :), except that I've hit some roadblocks during development due to missing dependencies or Windows components.  This one is with the Identity and Access Tool (as far as I can tell).

Here's my problem: I've created a blank VS12 solution, added an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application, hit F5 and everything runs perfectly.  Then, I configured the project to use the Local Development STS via the shiny new wizard (all default options), hit F5 and... the STS fails to respond when I get redirected to it.

Initial request:

```
GET http://localhost:4826/ HTTP/1.1
```

Response from the web application:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://localhost:12230/wsFederationSTS/Issue?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a4826%2f&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3dpassive%26ru%3d%252f&wct=2013-01-05T04%3a56%3a13Z
```

How do I go about troubleshooting the non-responsive STS?  I don't even know where it's running.  (That was one of few benefits of having your own STS project pre-WIF 4.5. :))

**EDIT (Jan. 5, 9:45 AM):** I've tried running the web application in IIS, rather than IIS Express - but with no success.  I've also uninstalled and reinstalled the *Identity and Access Tool* with no luck.

All the screenshots I've seen online show a notification icon for the LocalSTS service when you start debugging; I have yet to see this appear.

I've also compared the .csproj files before and after adding the STS configuration; I don't see any changes, not even a project type GUID added.  That makes me wonder if something is going wrong; how would the WIF tooling know to launch the LocalSTS if nothing in the project file specifies it?  Any ideas?  How is this mechanism supposed to work?

**EDIT (Jan. 5, 10:33 AM):** I installed the [Claims Aware MVC Application](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Claims-Aware-MVC-523e079b) sample and ran that, and the LocalSTS started up right away.  But after comparing the project files (.csproj, Web.config, etc.), I could find no meaningful difference that would flag the WIF tooling to start the LocalSTS for one project and not the other.  At least now I know the tooling is installed correctly.  Any thoughts on where I should look?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can't believe it, this is so painful it's funny. :)

Turns out, per scientific experimentation, the *Identity and Access Tool* will only start the LocalSTS for a WIF-configured MVC4 project **if the project is located under the root node of the solution, i.e. not underneath a solution folder.**

I guess I'm off to report a bug...  Glad it works now, though.

Comment: You can "manage" to make it work in the meanwhile right-clicking on the startup project and then selecting **Debug > Start new instance**. This starts the project in debugging mode **AND** the LocalSTS server as well.